# c# To verify excel file is damaged or not , if damaged then pop out a message box

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I am a new to c# and i am doing a window form program that to check the excel file is exist or not. If exists then need to verify the excel file is damaged or not , but i have no idea how to write the code . the part of searching excel file i had done .
#

```
        int point = 0;
            if (File.Exists(path1[0]))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sales " + Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + " Tranfser Error");
            point = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 1; x < path1.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(path1[x]))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Sales " + Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + " Transfer Error");
                    point = 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (File.Exists(path2[0]))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sales " + Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + " Transfer Successful");
            point = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 1; x < path2.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(path2[x]))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Sales " + Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + " Transfer Successful");
                    point = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (File.Exists(path3))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sales " + Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + " Havent Transfer");
            point = 1;
            }
        if (point == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No File of the date "+ Year +"-"+ Month +"-"+ Day);
        }
```

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE].  Edit your post to include an actual question.  "no idea how to write code" is not a valid question on SO.

Comment: What kind of file - .xls, xlsx or both?

Comment: I'm not certain but you could try to open it by some third party libs. If the file was damaged, the lib will not able to open it and throw an exception for you.

Comment: i am sorry, because i start to learning c# from here this week and this is my 1st time to asking question here // ,only .xlsx file //

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to check multiple paths for existence and file format? if so please construct your code better way. However the below function shall give you expected result. This uses EPPlus library, install it through nuget.

```
enum ExcelFileTestResult
{
    FileNotFound,
    ValidFormat, //File found, valid excel
    InvalidFormat //File found but not valid excel
}

public static ExcelFileTestResult CheckExcelFile(string path)
{
    ExcelFileTestResult result = ExcelFileTestResult.FileNotFound;
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
        try
        {
            // Trying to read file using EPPlus
            // if the file is not valid format, it will throw error
            using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(fi))
            {
                result = ExcelFileTestResult.ValidFormat;
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidDataException ex)
        {
            result = ExcelFileTestResult.InvalidFormat;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Note:* EPPlus works only for xlsx, not xls.
https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus