# Open and close all Excel files in a folder

Tags: c#

I am trying to open and immediately close all .xls files in a folder to determine which ones are corrupt (If I manually open a file that is corrupt, it will give me a message stating that it is corrupt and cannot be open). There are thousands of files in the folder. Here is what I have that doesn't seem to be working. I've placed it in a try catch block but that isn't showing any errors and nothing happens.

```
public void OpenXLSFiles()
{
    string[] folder = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\pricelist\", " *.xls");
    foreach (string file in folder)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbv = excel.Workbooks.Open(file);
        wbv.Close();
        excel.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbv);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
    }
}
```

To create a corrupt excel file create a new xlsx file and type some text in it. Save the file to your computer and rename the file with only .xls extension. This will cause it to be corrupt.

Comment: Do you have a way for us to manually corrupt a file to recreate the issue?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199121/c-sharp-to-verify-excel-file-is-damaged-or-not-if-damaged-then-pop-out-a-messa)

Comment: @MattRowland. Yes, create a new xlsx file and type some text in it. Save the file to your computer and rename the file with only .xls extension. This will cause it to be corrupt.

Comment: I got `COMException` with message *Excel cannot open the file 'Corrupted.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.* when trying to open corrupted file using Office Interop.

Comment: Your code is all correct, it crashes when some file is corrupt and you can put try catch block to identify the corrupted files. Just remove the space before *.xls
Put following line there instead.
string[] folder = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\pricelist\", "*.xls");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only mistake in your code is that you have put an extra space before *.xls in the search pattern. So, it doesn't even try to open any file. Please use the code below to mark corrupted files.

```
    public static void OpenXLSFiles()
    {
        string[] folder = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\pricelist\", "*.xls");
        foreach (string file in folder)
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbv = excel.Workbooks.Open(file);
                wbv.Close();
                excel.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbv);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File is corrupt : {0}", file));
            }
        }
    }
```